# Where is fee deduced from balance in the source code?

Tags: stellar-core

Simple question, but I failed to grep for the answer…

[It’s sayed balances are already deduced but where ? I mean which file and which line ?](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/master/src/transactions/TransactionFrame.cpp#L389)

> // if we are in applying mode fee was **already deduced from signing account**
>   // balance, if not, we need to check if after that deduction this account
>   // will still have minimum balance
>   uint32_t feeToPay = (applying && (header.current().ledgerVersion > 8))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in [LedgerManager:closeLedger](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/7fd4826c8267745c4a1047b7a3b343058cec1391/src/ledger/LedgerManagerImpl.cpp#L839) at first fees are applied with `processFeesSeqNums()` and 6 lines later transactions are applied with `applyTransactions()` => [tx->apply](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/7fd4826c8267745c4a1047b7a3b343058cec1391/src/ledger/LedgerManagerImpl.cpp#L1060) => [TransactionFrame:apply](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/3d5972dfa9ded39f645df3b7926d7c8b39f780a5/src/transactions/TransactionFrame.cpp#L635) => [TransactionFrame:commonValid( ..., true)](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/3d5972dfa9ded39f645df3b7926d7c8b39f780a5/src/transactions/TransactionFrame.cpp#L635)

Comment: This is the call stack of the line I gave. But as stated in the code, this is just a check as the fee is already substracted from `acc.balance`. So the real question is what’s the call chain that leads to `acc.balance` with the fee ?

Comment: Follow the part where I said "at first fees are applied" => processFeesSeqNums() => LedgerManagerImpl::processFeesSeqNums => tx->processFeeSeqNum() => TransactionFrame::processFeeSeqNum  where fee is deducted with `stellar::addBalance(acc.balance, -fee);`

Comment: Thank you… Just a last question : where transactions with negative fees are rejected ?